How can I fix some files through git branches?
I'm working on an application distributed with few brands. The differences between these brands is just logo images and some styles resource but all other contents are identical.
All brand versions are stored in different branches of a git repository.
I'm looking for some way to "fix" just these custom resources through all branches. In other words, I will need to often merge all branches with the main one, but I need to keep unmodified the brand resources even if the file seems not updated and a standard fast forward merge will overwrite it.
Is there any way to prevent file merge between branches in git?

If there are changes related to those adjustments for brand/images in each branch, then it's impossible that you get a fast-forward if you merge main into them.

There is not way to ignore some files? In some IDE I saw there is "assume unchanged" option for git integration, but I don't know it this is a git property or IDE function.

Say.... at this point, the question (the scenario) is not clear.... because of that, it's not possible to give you an accurate answer. Just in case, and given that you are the one asking for it in the comments, check git help update-index, specifically about --assume-unchanged..... I have a hunch that's not what you need but given that the scenario is not clear, I can't be really sure.

Deal with the endless merges or configure everything in one branch.
